# Why JQuery doesn't show a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

I'm having trouble with fading in another `div`, the ID id has 0 opacity, so the fadein effect should do the trick

```
//Opening
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#open').fadeOut('slow');
}, 9000); // <-- time in milliseconds

setTimeout(function() {
    $('#switch').fadeIn('slow');
}, 9000); // <-- time in milliseconds
```

the fade out works, but the fade in doesn't;  The `#open` is the id of one div, with opacity of 1, the `#switch` ID is another DIV which includes most of the content I got, which doesn't show.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: jsbin? cause it works fine for me http://jsbin.com/mikozoyahi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Instead of `opacity: 0` you should use `display: none` in your CSS. Alternatively, you should disclose more of your HTML and CSS code so we can answer your question properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot fadeIn something that is already into view (well you can, but you will not see any difference).  You need to start with the element hidden.

To illustrate this, I added the `display:none` on one of the elements (to bring it into view after the timeout)

```js
//Opening
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#open').fadeOut('slow');
}, 3000); // <-- time in milliseconds

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#switch').fadeIn('slow');
}, 3000); // <-- time in milliseconds
```

```css
#switch {
  background-color: #333;
  display: none;
  color: white;
}
#open {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="open">
  OPEN

</div>
<div id="switch">
  Switch
</div>
```

Comment: I dont want to delete my answer so I upvoted yours.... you were too quick for me :) should get accepted

Comment: Thank you!This is all i needed to finish my little app!

Answer (score 2):

To make it work, use the `fadeIn` use `display:none` instead:

```
<div id="open">
    hello
</div>
<div id="switch" style="display:none;">
    hodor
</div>
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.2.js"></script>
<script>
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#open').fadeOut('slow');
    }, 1000); // <-- time in milliseconds

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#switch').fadeIn('slow');
    }, 1000); // <-- time in milliseconds
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your div should be something like this

```
<div id="open">Fade out div</div>
<div id="switch" style="opacity: 1; display: none;">Fade in div</div>
```

Jquery code

```
setTimeout(function() {
$('#open').fadeOut('slow');
}, 9000); // <-- time in milliseconds



setTimeout(function() {
$('#switch').fadeIn();
}, 9000); // <-- time in milliseconds
```